# Textarea disappears after setting value

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, settimeout

Here's what I'm trying to do:

Type initials (e.g. MS,AK,LT) by clicking on "Enter Names". This saves a string, which I then turn into an array (nameArray) in order to get each set of initials. After reordering these randomly, I want to place some of the initials into the textareas, but that's where things go wrong.

Here's what's wrong:

the initials display for a moment, then disappear after the function executes. (ALSO, I'm trying to have a div (with text "randomizing...") that is otherwise hidden, show itself for 4 seconds (4000 ms) while the initials are being reordered to indicate as such. That's what the setTimeout is for...but that doesn't work either. The div disappears along with the text). Why are these only in coordination with the execution of the function?

Here's the JS code:

```
var nameArray;

window.onload = pageLoad;

function pageLoad() {
    $("#randomizingNotification").hide();
    $("#prev_arrow").click(prevUser);
    $("#next_arrow").click(nextUser);
    $("#enter_names").click(orderNames);    
}

function orderNames() {
    nameArray = getNames();
    randomizeNames();
    displayNames();
}

function getNames() {
    var initialsString = prompt("Please enter initials, separated by a comma (e.g LK,AS,NM)");
    nameArray = initialsString.split(",");
    return nameArray;
}

function randomizeNames() {
    $("#randomizingNotification").show();
    var timer = setTimeout(function(){randomize(nameArray);},4000);
    $("#randomizingNotification").hide();
    clearTimeout(timer);
}

function randomize(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
        var randNum = Math.floor(array.length*Math.random()) //random number between 0 and length of array (rounded down
        var temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[randNum];
        array[randNum] = temp;
    }
}

function displayNames() {
    var curr, up, prev, current, upcoming, previous;
    curr = 0;
    up = 1;
    prev = null

    current = nameArray[curr];
    upcoming = nameArray[up];

    $("#upcoming_pick").val(upcoming);
    $("#current_pick").val(current);
}
```

Here's the relevant HTML code:

```
<body>
<div id="header">
    <div id="randomizeNotContDiv">
        <div id="randomizingNotification">randomizing...</div>
    </div>

    <div id="page_title"><h1>Welcome to Classtech Shift Scheduler!</h1></div>

    <div id="helper_functions_div">
        <div id="enter_names_div">
            <a href="" id="enter_names">Enter Names</a>
        </div>
   </div>
```

```
<div id="main_content">
    <div id="name_tracker">

        <div><a href="" alt="prev" id="prev_arrow"><img src="Images/prev_arrow.png"/></a></div>

        <textarea name="upcoming_pick" cols="10" rows="1" class="picker_names" id="upcoming_pick"></textarea>
        <textarea name="current_pick" cols="10" rows="1" class="picker_names" id="current_pick"></textarea>
        <textarea name="previous_pick" cols="10" rows="1" class="picker_names" id="previous_pick"></textarea>

        <div><a href="" alt="next" id="next_arrow"><img src="Images/next_arrow.png"/></a></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Create a jsfiddle.net

Comment: I have seen "textarea" specified - not sure if it makes a difference. i.e. $("textarea#upcoming_pick").val(upcoming);

Comment: @d'alar'cop Nope, thanks tho.

Comment: Your `randomizeNames` function does strictly bugger all.

Comment: What do you mean? the randomizeNames function works and just rearranges the elements in the array.

Comment: What is the point of showing the loader for a fixed amount of time?

Comment: The `randomizeNames` function sets a timer and then clears it immediately. The timer will never trigger.

Comment: @Juhana- the point is just to tell the user what's happening. That is,  the order of initials is being determined. If I don't set a timer, it will do so automatically. How do I set the timer such that the div becomes visible for a second or two then returns to hidden.

Comment: I understand what its function is, but why have it show always exactly 4 seconds? Why have the user wait for nothing if the calculation has already been done? Why not show the notification when the calculation starts and hide it as soon as it's finished?

Comment: Because the calculation is done in less than a second. The notification would appear then disappear before the user knows what happened. That's not a huge deal for the program, but I thought it would be a fun addition and don't understand why it's disappearing so quickly.

Comment: That's a valid UI feature, though there might be other ways of doing it. Forcing the user to wait for four seconds does seem a bit annoying. But I've explained the reason you're having trouble with the instantaneous disappearing in my answer below.

Comment: @Nate- now that it works, 4 seconds is a lot. I've reduced it, but see comment below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got at least few issues, but the main problem is the structure of your setTimeout. A setTimeout is like an AJAX call in that it's non-blocking. Anything inside the function you pass to it will only execute when the timer is done, while code that comes after it will execute *immediately*.

I've reorganized the hiding of your randomization message and the displayNames function to go inside of the setTimeout function and things work fine.

Here it is in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nate/LB6dz/

And here's the code:

```
var nameArray;

window.onload = pageLoad;

function pageLoad() {
    $("#randomizingNotification").hide();
    $("#enter_names").click(orderNames);    
}

function orderNames(event) {
    // Prevent the link's default action
    event.preventDefault();

    nameArray = getNames();
    randomizeNames();
}

function getNames() {
    var initialsString = prompt("Please enter initials, separated by a comma (e.g LK,AS,NM)");
    nameArray = initialsString.split(",");
    return nameArray;
}

function randomizeNames() {
    $("#randomizingNotification").show();
    var timer = setTimeout(function (){
        randomize(nameArray);
        // These items need to be inside the timeout, so they only run once it's done
        $("#randomizingNotification").hide();
        displayNames();
    }, 4000);
    // No need to clearTimeouts after they're done... they only run once
    // clearTimeout(timer);
}

function randomize(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
        var randNum = Math.floor(array.length*Math.random()) //random number between 0 and length of array (rounded down
        var temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[randNum];
        array[randNum] = temp;
    }
}

function displayNames() {
    var curr, up, prev, current, upcoming, previous;
    curr = 0;
    up = 1;
    prev = null

    current = nameArray[curr];
    upcoming = nameArray[up];

    $("#upcoming_pick").val(upcoming);
    $("#current_pick").val(current);
}
```

Comment: this works more like I'd like, except this time, the initial are displayed BEFORE the randomizeNotification disappears. Is there a way to coordinate it so that doesn't happen? Maybe set another timeout function?

Comment: I haven't checked any browser other than Chrome, but that's not what's happening in my example. Are you checking my fiddle, or did you just update your own code? The displayNames function doesn't get called until the timer runs out. There's definitely not a need to set another setTimeout. The important thing is understanding the order of execution in your existing setTimeout correctly.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Good luck!